# How i can add permission in a field collection, only for one field

Tags: drupal, collections, permissions, field

I want add permission only on one field in a field collection, for a special user. Thx for help.

Comment: Dude. you should at least show your work here people can't help you here.. and it would cause down-votes on your question.. please read the guidelines here on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Minimal reply for minimal question: use hook_form_alter and set #access to the form field when the current  user (via gloabl $user) uid matches the uid you want.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it programmatically you can find this functionality with the Field Permissions module : https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions